# Why is $\sum_{i}m_iv_i$ equal to zero for a rolling ball?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I was watching a video about rotational kinetic energy in which they derived the formula $$K=\dfrac{1}{2}mv^2+\dfrac{1}{2}I\omega^2$$

each point on the circle has a translational velocity equal to the velocity of the center of mass $v_{CM}$, and a tangential rotational velocity $v_i$.the derivation is similar to the following. I will use $v^2=v\cdot v$ and $uv=u\cdot v$ $$K = \sum_i\dfrac{1}{2}m_i(v_{CM}+v_i)^2$$
$$K=\sum_i\dfrac{1}{2}m_iv_{CM}^2+m_iv_{CM}v_i+\dfrac{1}{2}m_iv_i^2$$
$$K=\sum_i\dfrac{1}{2}m_iv_{CM}^2+v_{cm}\left(\sum_im_iv_i\right)+\sum_i\dfrac{1}{2}m_iv_i^2$$
at which point they claim it simplifies to
$$K=\sum_i\dfrac{1}{2}m_iv_{CM}^2+\sum_i\dfrac{1}{2}m_iv_i^2$$
as $$\sum_im_iv_i=0$$
I am interested in why this is true and if it is possible to prove it. I understand why this would be true if the mass was evenly distributed but that was never stated to be assumed in the video.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Jaden and welcome to PSE. The mass need not be evenly distributed for the sum you describe to be zero. This is simply a statement that if one divides a system to a discrete collection of small masses $m_i$, each moving with velocity $\upsilon_i$, there will always be a mass $m_j,\ j\ne i$ (maybe on the opposite site of the mass $m_i$ with respect to the rotation axis), such that $m_j\upsilon_j=-m_i\upsilon_i$. Therefore, the contributions from $i$ and $j$ cancel, and one can divide one's system in a way (take many more and masses and lighter ones as well) such that this is true always.

Comment: Because this is how we defined the center of mass.

Comment: Your two velocities (cm, i) are not parallel.  This makes your formula for uv incorrect.  At the bottom of the ball, v_i exactly opposes v_cm, making the sum zero.  At the top, they are in the same direction.  Here v_cm+v_i=2v_cm.  When you leave 2 dimensions, you need trigonometry when you work point by point.  This is the convenience of rotational motion as part of rolling motion.  The trigonometry effects are summed within the rotational inertia and angular velocity.

Comment: @KenMellendorf:  Alternately, if the products of the $v$'s are replaced by dot products, the proof goes through exactly as the OP has written it out.

Comment: This does seem like a conceptual question, not a "question focused on a particular calculation".  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This $v_{i}$ is not just a random $v_{i}$ in an arbitrary frame, this $v_{i}$ is the velocity of the ith point mass with respect to the centre of mass. a suggestive way to write it is $v_{i/c}$. Note that the centre of mass velocity with respect to a given frame f is given by (by definition) $$ v_{c/f}= \frac{\sum m_{i}v_{i/f}}{\sum m_{i}} $$

We also make use of the fact that the velocity of the centre of mass with respect to the centre of mass is 0, obviously.

Now if we computationally calculate the centre of mass velocity, with respect to the centre of mass using the above formula, we see that $$ 0=\frac{\sum m_{i}v_{i/c}}{\sum m_{i}}$$

Since the denominator is obviously a positive number, the numerator term $ \sum m_{i}v_{i/c} $ must be 0.